gitlab: ci nuget packages versioning
I am building and pushing nuget packages using gitlab CI. whenever the package is pushed to the nuget repository in gitlab, it appends the name of the branch.
this is my ci pipeline:
.vars-readstores:
  variables:
    PROJECT_NAME: "EventFlow.ReadStores"
    PROJECT_ROOT: "Pathway.Packages/$PROJECT_NAME"
    PROJECT_PATH: "$PROJECT_ROOT/$PROJECT_NAME.csproj"
    PACKAGE_VERSION: "2.0.0"
    

readstores-build:
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0
  extends:
    - .vars-readstores
  stage: nuget-build
  before_script:
    - dotnet nuget add source 
  script:
    - dotnet restore $PROJECT_PATH
    - dotnet build $PROJECT_PATH -c Release
    - dotnet pack $PROJECT_PATH -c Release 
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - $PROJECT_ROOT/bin/Release/*.nupkg

readstores-push:
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0
  extends:
    - .vars-readstores
  stage: nuget-push
  dependencies:
    - readstores-build
  script:    
    - |
      dotnet nuget add source "$CI_SERVER_URL/api/v4/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/packages/nuget/index.json" --name gitlab --username gitlab-ci-token --password $CI_JOB_TOKEN --store-password-in-clear-text
      echo "Pushing package to registry."
      ORIGINAL_PACKAGE=$(ls $PROJECT_ROOT/bin/Release/*.nupkg)
      mv "$ORIGINAL_PACKAGE" "$PROJECT_ROOT/bin/Release/${PROJECT_NAME}.${PACKAGE_VERSION}.nupkg"
      dotnet nuget push "$PROJECT_ROOT/bin/Release/*.nupkg" --source gitlab
  when: manual

this is the metadata of .csproj file
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <PackageId>EventFlow.ReadStores</PackageId>
    <Version>2.0.0</Version>
  </PropertyGroup>

